# What are the best practices to test performance and scalability of Message Oriented Middleware (MOM) solutions?

Tags: performance, jms, scalability, messaging, amqp

We are looking for a software that will help to decide which MOM solution should be used in a given case, taking into account throughput and latency figures it measures.

Not to reinvent the wheel we'd like to investigate what solutions already exist on the market.

For example, there are:

1. [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) with its [Point-to-Point Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html) and [Topic Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html)
2. [QPID](http://qpid.apache.org/) [performance and latency test utils](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Messaging_User_Guide/chap-Messaging_User_Guide-Optimization.html)
3. [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org) [JMeter performance test](http://activemq.apache.org/jmeter-performance-tests.html)
4. [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) [performance test](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/hornetq/trunk/examples/jms/perf/)
5. [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) [performance test](https://gist.github.com/935196)
6. [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker)

It seems there are no tools to test performance and latency of these MOMs somehow in a general way.

So could you please recommend tools which worth looking at or some ideas how to implement such a tool in a cross-platform, cross-language way.

Answer (score 2):

While someone may know a tool to test them all I'd recommend that you build a testing scenario that resembles your intended use (message sized, integration patterns (e.g. do you need CBR and if so what), required latencies, message rates, target environment etc.)
Synthetic benchmarks can be misleading and will most likely not represent your usage scenario

As a side note I'd say that AMQP has the advantage that it also defines the wire protocol so if you choose one you can change the backend without affecting the client

Comment: I understand it, but if you have to choose some messaging system for the first time, synthetic benchmarks can be rather useful too.

Answer (score -1):

What about [SPEC JMS 2007](https://www.spec.org/jms2007/) ??? I think it would be quite usefull for your case :)

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.

Comment: You are completely right Kyll! You definitely know all the rules and I admire the fact that you guide the other users how to follow them. But I just wanna ask you why you comment my answer and not the question itself, and why it was not closed before I answered to it?
I think if something is against the rules you have to deal with its root not with me. There are much more recomendations in the first post. 

Don not get me wrong here, I just feel your post more like altercation than a constructive critique. :)

Anyway, no matter here. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Well, thing is, this question was asked and answered five years ago. Rules have changed since then. This question was basically dead, but due to this new answer it popped up on the front-page where it was spotted by a chat room ([SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)). Once it was spotted it was promptly closed. If you wish to discuss further, please feel free to drop into [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) =)